# How to use custom fonts for a Wine application?

Tags: wine, fonts

My windows application needs specialized fonts. The fonts ship with the application so I don't need to download any extra fonts. When I installed the application it automatically installed the fonts to `/home/<user>/.wine/drive_c/windows/Fonts`.

However, the fonts were not displayed in the application when I ran it. The vendor said the fonts must not be installed correctly. So I manually copied the fonts to `/home/<user>/.fonts/` and restarted the computer. However, the problem was still not resolved.

Next I used Kubuntu's Font Management tool and it verified that the required fonts are listed as installed. I'm not sure what to do next to make the fonts available to the application. Any suggestions?